# How to remove broken hinge which is stuck inside

Tags: doors, metal, hinges, rust

There is a broken hinge which is stuck:

[image: broken hinge]

To compare, a good hinge is removed easily like this:

[image: good hinge]

I tried to remove broken hinge with a hammer, however it is stuck very firmly. Is there any method to remove the broken hinge? The rust makes removal harder.

Comment: The usual remedies are a penetrant and heat, along with a little tappy-tappy.

Comment: @isherwood the broken section belongs to the door, but it is broken and stuck.

Comment: A drill bit may work if the bottom hinge side is not solid thru-out the hinge? (i.e the hinge itself will keep the drill where it needs to be).

Comment: there may be a device that prevents the lifting of the door off the hinges .... perhaps a set screw or a pin or a clip of some type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That style of hinge is generally made from a pair of metal cups and a piece of round bar.

It definitely looks like a good candidate for heat. There will be damage done to the surrounding paint. Either warm the top piece with a torch, or cut the whole thing off and weld in a new hinge. It looks as if there's welding to be done there anyway to re-attach the hinge to the door.

If a torch isn't available but a welder is, and if you'd really rather not cut off the lower piece of hinge, then you could weld a couple beads up the exterior of the top portion and grind them off later. As an added bonus such beads might give better grip to the locking pliers you'd want to use to grab and twist the hot hinge.

Comment: Right, I have to weld the broken section to the door